# Enabling Sync to VBLank on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

How to enable Sync to VBLANK on Xubuntu? I can't find settings for it. I have Nvidia GeForce 7600 card with proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `nvidia-settings` utility (it comes in the `nvidia-settings` package or its installed with the proprietary drivers from the Nvidia website).

To run it type on a terminal `gksudo nvidia-settings`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little leap of faith, but if you're trying to improve video playback quality (ie stop tearing etc), in addition to enabling vblank in your video card settings (both Nvidia nd ATI provide their own proprietry settings managers for this), you need to also disable display compositing. (Settings Manager -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Compositor, untick the top checkbox)

This will unfortunately remove some of the prettier effects like transparency in terms and so on, but is necessary for flawless video playback in xfce.

Apologies if I'm barking up the wrong tree here :)